# MFC Multiline tooltip with member method

Tags: c++, mfc

I used the following method for adding tooltips to my controls:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/141758

Howver, i can't make those tooltips be multiline (at `\r\n` escape chars). How could this be done?

I tried implementing something similar to the answer in [Are multiline tooltips possible using CWnd::EnableTooltips()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134329/are-multiline-tooltips-possible-using-cwndenabletooltips), adding a handler for `TTN_NEEDTEXT` in my dialog. This is being called, but the tooltip is not multiline and the `\r\n` chars are displayed as regular chars.

Comment: Can you show where you handle TTN_NEEDTEXT?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti What do you want me to paste exactly? I handle it in my dialog

Comment: Code related to _"...I tried implementing something similar to the answer..."_

Answer (score 3):

The big trick, and it is not obvious by any means, is that you have to call `SetMaxTipWidth()` on the tooltip control. It looks superfluous and that it would not have an effect of whether you can have multi-line tooltips, but it is the key.

Comment: I am already doing this, `CToolTipCtrl* pToolTip = AfxGetThreadState()->m_pToolTip;
pToolTip->SetMaxTipWidth(SHRT_MAX);`